# Perl add value 1 to value 2 value 2 to value 3 etc to end of file

Tags: perl, data-manipulation

I have a Perl question which should be fairly easy but can’t quite seem to get it correct  I have a file that contains 2 columns of numbers, what I need to is to take the second column and add the first value in this column to the second, the second to the third the third to the fourth etc. I don’t know how many numbers will be in column 2 so I need to do this until the end of the file, I also want to be able to use these values further on in my program. I will give a dummy example below along with the code I have tried so far.

Example file tab delimited file data.txt

```
1   29
2   26
3   24
4   28
```

Example of desired out put

```
55

50

52
```

Code as is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# use and library files
use strict;
use warnings;


my $line;
my $Val;
my $sum;
open(FH, "data.txt") or die $!;
while (my $line = <FH>){
my @val = split("\t", $line);
my $Val = $val[1];
my $sum = $Val+$Val;
print "$sum\n";
}
close FH;
```

The line $sum = $Val+$Val;  needs to have some sort of loop so the correct values are being added but not sure how to get it right, and then I need to somehow assign the summed values variable names to use later.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance 
Sinead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it almost in your example. `$Val` is your previous value. So you must not overwrite it before you used it in the $sum. This means swap these two lines and add the previous and the current value.

```
my $sum = $Val+$val[1];
my $Val = $val[1];
```

One advice, try to give distinct names to variables. Differences in case only easily lead to confusion.

Here's my version

```
my $prev = 0;
while (<>) {
    my(@cols) = split;
    my $sum = $prev + $cols[1];
    $prev = $cols[1];
    print "$sum\n" if ($. > 1); # skip first line
}
```

and call it with

```
perl sum.pl data.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much,this is perfect. I thought I was close. :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily with a one-liner:

```
perl -lanwe 'push @a, $F[1]; 
             next if @a < 2; print $a[0]+$a[1]; shift @a;" nums.csv
```

**Output:**

```
55
50
52
```

**Explanation:**

This is the deparsed code for the one-liner:

```
while (<>) {              # comes from the -n switch
    chomp;                # remove line ending, -l switch does this
    our(@F) = split;      # split the input line, -a switch does this
    push @a, $F[1];       # buffer the second field
    next if @a < 2;       # check buffer size
    print $a[0] + $a[1];  # print sum
    shift @a;             # remove first value from buffer
}
```

In summary:

- `-l` handles your line endings for you
- `-a` autosplits the input lines on whitespace. You may supply the split pattern yourself with the `-F` switch, e.g. `-F"\t"`.
- `-n` puts a `while(<>)` loop around your code. This effectively takes the arguments as file names and loops through the file contents.
- `-w` enables warnings, which is a good thing.